# WebWiew - Open multiple windows

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to create a WebWiew app that's will download multiple files - by opening multiple windows - each window with another file url. (using window.open() in js)

My code:

```
package aviad.com.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://matanya.hagitbagno.co.il/dafYomi/index.html";
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

when ever you click download button/url it will call `shouldOverrideUrlLoading and onDownloadStart` two method will called, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`will not do anything in this case but,but `onDownloadStart` can help us to fix your issue.
keep `setDownloadListener` to your webview like following.

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onDownloadStart: ");
            if (Util.isOurServer(url)) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setType(mimetype);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            //registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


        }
```